# Multiple generic types fields in class C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a class with multiple generic types fields, something like this:

```
class Objeto<T> where T, U, W : class, new()
{
   private T field1;
   private U field2;
   private List<W> listField;
}
```

But I don't know how do it.

Comment: You mean like `Objeto<T, U, W>`? Or is your confusion with `where`? Or something else?

Comment: @Llama yeah, my confusion was with were, but TimChang give me the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Objeto<T, U, W> 
    where T: class, new() 
    where U : class, new()
    where W : class, new()
{
    private T field1;
    private U field2;
    private List<W> listField;
}
```